# How to query on array field with an aray in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

Example of a document in a dummy collection.

```mongodb
{
    "_id": "1",
    "subjects": ['English', 'Maths', 'Science', 'French',..]
}
```

Now I want to select all the documents which are having any of the subjects mentioned in an array. Eg: `['Maths', 'French']`.

So the result of the query should give all the documents wherever any of the subjects that are mentioned.

Therefore for the above examples, all the document's which are having `Maths` or `French`  `subjects` should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$in` operator with `find()` or `aggregate()`

```
db.collection.find({
  "subjects": {
    $in: [
      "English"
    ]
  }
})
```

Or

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      subjects: {
        $in: [
          "Maths",
          "English"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kVhRNZA-CZ8)